# Can I stop .net 4.0 from encoding single quotes?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, encoding, .net-4.0

After switching to .net 4.0, some javascript code from a third party gridview crashes.
It has got something to do with [HtmlEncode and UrlEncode now encode single quotation marks](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770143)

So before some code on the page was inserted like this:
`DataItem.GetMember('Id').Value`

and now its like this: `DataItem.GetMember(&#39;Id&#39;).Value`

The gridview does an `eval` on that line, and crashes with a syntax error now. I can't change the javascript code in that gridview.

Is there anyway to solve this, without going backwards like this?

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" />
```

**EDIT: the pages controlRenderingCompatiblityVersion doesn't fix this also. Single quotes are still encoded.**

Comment: are you using webforms or mvc?

Comment: Interesting problem. "eval" is evil, so it's unfortunate you're stuck with it. :(

Comment: It looks like i can change the code that ends up in the eval before it goes into the black box, so i'm fine. But i'll leave the question open for others who bump into the same problem

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read, it's a security feature and Microsoft is mum about changing it.  The only work-around I've seen is you will need to create a custom encoder class.  You can turn-off attribute encoding using this:

```
public class HtmlAttributeEncodingQuote : System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder
{
    protected override void HtmlAttributeEncode(string value, System.IO.TextWriter output)
    {
        output.Write(value);
    }
}
```

Then add this to web.config under **system.web**:

```
<httpRuntime encoderType="HtmlAttributeEncodingQuote"/>
```